# angular/material2 - mdSelect - How to display form value as initial value using objects

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

Alright, I am trying to build a form component that has a `mdSelect` which uses options that are actually objects.

let's say:

```
...
export class MyFormComponent implements OnInit {

 showing: boolean = false;
 form: FormGroup;
 options$: Observable<MyModel[]>;

 constructor(
  public fb: FormBuilder,
  public data: MyDataService
 )

 ngOnInit() {
  this.form = fb.group({myField: ['']});
  this.options$ = this.data.fetch();
 }

 editRecord(record: any) {
   this.form.patchValue(record);
   this.showing = true;
 }

}
```

this is where values come from:

```
fetch(search?: URLSearchParams): Observable<Response> {
 return this.http.request({
  method: RequestMethod.Get,
  url: this.getEndpoint(),
  search: search
 });
}
```

and my html:

```
<div class="myForm">
  <md-select placeholder="Choose one" formControlName="myField">
    <md-option *ngFor="let opt of options$ | async" [value]="opt">{{opt.someInnerField}}</md-option>
  </md-select>
</div>
```

When this component of mine is used to insert a new record it works properly, but when I call `editRecord()` the `mdSelect` won't show the `myField.someInnerField`, it don't show anything as if it was empty

Comment: just out of interest, if you have `this.options$ = this.data.fetch();` in `editRecord` does it make a difference ?

Comment: No :( @Searching